# authentication failure on new arch install

Tags: arch-linux, login, pam

I'm setting up a new machine running Arch and after going through the beginner's guide I rebooted into the machine and when trying to log in as my user or as root with correct passwords I get back the "Login Incorrect" error.

How I can debug this? All I see in journalctl is this (I tried logging in 3 times, twice for root and once for my user)

```
login[285]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost= user=root
login[285]: FAILED LOGIN 1 tty1 FOR root, authentication failure
login[285]: FAILED LOGIN 2 tty1 FOR root, authentication failure
login[285]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost= user=dillon
login[285]: FAILED LOGIN 3 tty1 FOR dillon, authentication failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed that the issue was my password contained symbols. In particular it contained the symbols "#" and "!". I'm assuming it was the "!" that was causing issues, but after changing the password to "hi" it seemed to let me log in.

**EDIT:** I found out what the real issue was.

My keymapping was set to something like "de-latin" instead of "us" and the "#" in my password was looking like this in the tty *<77777777><77777777>*. I didn't see this before because the password field does not show any characters.

**tl;dr** If you are having trouble logging in with your correct username and password make sure your keymaps are set correctly!